# Linux Deploy: Making new disk image (size) ... fail

Tags: samsung, installation, linux

I am trying to use Linux Deploy on my rooted Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3 / Slimkat 4.4.4. But when I press install:

```
Updating configuration file ... done
>>> begin install
Checking mount points ... done
Checking installation path ... done
Making new disk image (1023 MB) ... fail
<<< end: install
```

Answer (score -1):

go to installation type and select custom, then put a path you want and install it.